# Selenium and openpyxl : writing data in row major form

Tags: excel, selenium, openpyxl

I'm new to openpyxl, and I need some help here. Basically I retrieve a particular link,

```
writestring = link.get_attribute("href")
```

I get these links one by one for each item, and for each item, I need to write these links in an excel sheet in a single row. For eg, if I have 3 links for item 1, I need to write these three in A1, B1, C1; then if I have 5 links for item 2, I need to write them in A2, B2,..., E2 and so on.

How can I accomplish this task? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You'll need 2 counters, 1 to keep track of which item you're dealing with, which gives you your row to write to, and a second that holds the number of links you need to write, which gives you your column.
ie `for item in items: for link in links: writeToSpreadsheet(link.text, item.index, link.index)`

Obviously the above isn't even accurate code but hopefully you can use it to form a proper function

Answer (score 0):

Largely because of the underlying format it's best to write in rows to openpyxl using the `.append()` method. It would be easier to help you if you have some more code.